# Adding css to file via php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin which I would like it to add some predefined CSS to a stylesheet when someone enables a feature.

I cannot simply include the stylesheet in addition to the regular stylesheet because some features will conflict with it. I would like it so that when they click one element it loads only the CSS relevant to this.

When they select this element it should "print" the relevant CSS into a stylesheet.

Can I call a function that I created which contains CSS and gets called only once the feature is enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways I would approach this.

You can use use inline css and not require the theme's style sheet. And write what you need between your conditions, like this the first example or use `wp_add_inline_style`.

#### IDEA 1: *not* using wp_add_inline_style

```
//* Load CSS
function yourplugin_prefix_load_css() {
     add_action( 'wp_head', 'yourpluginprefix_css', 15 );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded' , 'yourplugin_prefix_load_css' );


//* CSS
function yourpluginprefix_css() {

    //vars
    $a = get_option( 'where_a', 'what_a' );
    $b = get_option( 'where_b', 'what_b' );

    // begin CSS
    $css = '';

    $css .= '<style class="whatever" >';

    //condition $a
    if ( $a == '0' ) :

        $css .= '

            .property{
                display: inline-block;
            }

        '; 

    endif;  //condition for $a


    //condition $b
    if ( $b != '1' ) :

        $css .= '

            .property-something{
                border: 1px solid #333;
            }

        '; 

    endif;  //condition for $b


    //close the style sheet
    $css .= '</style>';

    //minify it
    $css_min = str_replace( array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $css );

    echo $css_min;

}
```

### IDEA 2 with wp_add_inline_style

Alternatively, you can use wp_add_inline_style and get the current theme's handle .

```
function pluginprefix_css() {

    //get current theme stylesheet handle
    $current_theme = ( wp_get_theme() );

    //get our values for conditions
    $a             = get_option( 'where_a', 'what_a' );
    $b             = get_option( 'where_b', 'what_b' );


    //begin css
    $css = '';


    //condition $a
    if ( $a == '0' ) :

        $css .= '

            .property{
                display: inline-block;
            }

        '; 

    endif;  //condition for $a


    //condition $b
    if ( $b != '1' ) :

        $css .= '

            .property-something{
                border: 1px solid #333;
            }

        '; 

    endif;  //condition for $b      


    //minify css
    $css_min = str_replace( array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $css );

    //add inline style                
    wp_add_inline_style( $current_theme->stylesheet, $css_min );


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pluginprefix_css' );
```

Comment: YES LEGEND!!! Thanks so much. I made a small change and changed:
"$css .= str_replace(" to "$css_min .= str_replace(" and then exho $css_min. As your code was outputting both minified and not.

THANKS SO MUCH!! EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED! YAY

Comment: Good catch. I modified it from my plugin too fast. I updated the answer.

Comment: I added an option where you can use wp_add_inline and the handle is the theme's stylesheet, makes it much more WordPress friendly. Not much to change, except you don't need opening and closing style tags and you need to add the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to load library after the site is loaded, your best hope is javascript.
E.g. you can add code snippet into head when click on element. In jQuery

```
var e = 'button.class';
var remove_css = '#my_style_1';
var code = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/css_part.css">';
$(e).on( 'click', function() {
   $('head').append( code );
   $(remove_css).remove();
});
```

Replace e variable with class or element which will add code into header on click.

**UPDATED:** find in source the identificator (ID) of your css file and put it in remove_css variable. It will remove it after element clicked. I should note that this solution is not persistent and lasts until page switch.

--

If you need load css based on option, create an option in your admin, register your styles and then enable it based on option.

Somewhere in code register your style:

```
wp_register_style( 'my_style_original', '/path/to/css_part.css' );
wp_register_style( 'my_style_replace', '/path/to/css_part.css' );
```

And then eneable it based on option

```
$enable_css = get_option( 'enable_css' );
if( $enable_css )
   wp_enqueue_style( 'my_style_replace' );   // if setting enabled load second css
else
   wp_enqueue_style( 'my_style_original' );   // if setting not enabled load original css
```

This will load the style only when option 'enable_css' is not false or empty.
To create option page see https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages or for easier setup you can stick to ACF options (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/options-page/);

Comment: if I get you correctly. I will have multiple css files with the codes in them. The code above will take the css and will load it in the head of the site and not link the stylesheet? Might be on to a winner there

Comment: I will update both solututions to replace the style/load only one at while.

Comment: This will load an external sheet right? If I have 4-5 features enabled then I will have 4-5 external sheets loading? thanks

Comment: I should ask first what are you trying to achieve. You need this setting to be persistent (eg. admin will set it in admin and it will load libraries on frontend everytime) or it's just one shot purpose on specific page on the site?

Comment: So basically I have some css that changes the look of the blog posts on the archive pages. When they select and option it will show them as grid format (masonry). if they select another option will show as full width. So basically the two css codes conflict. But then I have other options that can also be "enabled" so need those scripts to be added to the css file too.

To answer your questions: it will be loaded throughout the site as is on many pages.

Comment: Okay. I would recommend (if its possible) to change the way styles behave -> not override but base its loading on parent class, so you would only change parent classes (on parent element/container) with javascript and get rid of the unnecessary work we are discoussing (its like switching themes). If the code is too long or you don't want to refactorize it you have to do it this way and then you have few options. **1)** do javascript logic with cookies (to save changes for browser, while browsing several different pages) which will asynchronously load appropriate styles based on cookie.

Comment: **2)** or with PHP using session variable. See https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp for further info and combine it with PHP solution i posted above.

Comment: Solution 1) is good when you need to save setting for future (after site was closed) 2) is simplier to implement but will last only on session (till site was closed and visitor left)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - the answer below helped me but really appreciate your input

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that writes indented style into the specific element. Remember that this is not considered bad coding, anyway I don't know how it'd be considered since it'd be dynamic content.

So, for example, you have:

```
<input type="text" />
```

And when the user clicks to add the style, the function would add:

```
<input type="text" style="..." />
```

In the other hand, when the user refreshes the page, the style would disappear.

Comment: While it'd work, this is a messy way to go about it and difficult to maintain.

Comment: Oh yes, yes it is.

Comment: yh thanks. Not sure this would work like I want it to.. The user will click a button in wordpress backend and will post css into a file that will load in the frontend. Also there might be a large chunk of css so not sure it will be easy your way. Thanks for the help.

Dont know if there is a way to "put" css into a style.css file.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - the answer above helped me but really appreciate your input

Answer (score 0):

Create a php function that takes the arguments of what features are enabled to make a custom stylesheet, and dynamically enqueue that stylesheet. Use .htaccess or similar settings to redirect requests for your `custom_thingy.css` to `custom_thingy.php` and just have it echo the custom styles, it'll behave like a regular stylesheet.

```
foreach($style_options as $option) {
    echo file_get_contents($option_style_file[$option]);
}
```

Comment: I thought about this but then I will have multiple css sheets loading. So if they enable 4-5 features I will have five sheets loading? is that what you mean? Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Sorta. Make your multiple sheets, and have a php script that brings them all together when they're needed and echos it out as a stylesheet.
Similar to what 'cache' plugins do, compile all the files into one, only including what you need.

Comment: Ok I see. Do you know how to write a script that brings them all together?

Comment: Pseudocode, but something like this would be a start:


    `foreach($style_options as $option) {
        echo file_get_contents($option_style_file[$option]);
    }`

Comment: If I want to redirect the .css file to the .php file. How would I do this via the plugin as dont have access to everyones htaccess? can this be done via the plugin? Thanks again

Comment: For simplicity, maybe you can make a temporary css file via the PHP code and just load that?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - the answer above helped me but really appreciate your input

Answer (score 0):

if you using wordpress. you can use **[wp_add_inline_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style)**